# Why can't I delete this item? Doesn't make sense

Tags: php, jquery, post, load, get

So hopefully someone with admin privileges will see this and delete it for me.

Answer (score 1):

From a semantic standpoint, you should go with hyperlinks in the HTML using the anchor tag. However, if the variables you need to pass contain critical information that you cannot risk being modified, you could consider using jQuery to POST the information instead. The disadvantage to using just JavaScript would be, of course, if JavaScript was disabled.

You could do both methods, however. If you place an anchor tag with GET variables and then use jQuery to attach a POST onclick, the JavaScript would trump the `href`. This way, under typical circumstances, the variables would be POST'ed. Under circumstances when JavaScript is unavailable, the variables would be GET'ed. You could then check in your PHP script that is processing the data which one happened (POST or GET) and with GET, do some extra error checking or processing to make sure the data is *exactly* what you expect. Of course, the big disadvantage to this is having to main the hyperlink and JavaScript URL in two places if anything changes.

**EDIT:** Reading this again, I started to think: Quite honestly, if you go with my suggestion and write extra error checking or processing code for the GET, it wouldn't hurt to run it on the POST either. And if that's the case, you might as well just do a GET and skip the JavaScript. It'll save you the overhead.